# Given an Amazon Web Service Security Group, how can I find out what the IP's are?

Tags: security, firewall, amazon-web-services, filtering

I'm looking at using a cloud service which has [an AWS Security group](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/)...

[image]

I've got a hardware firewall and a software firewall.

I have no idea how to say: Given that security group, allow any traffic from that security group IP range, but only to ports 1234 on MY server.

Is this possible?

I know most people will say "What's the hardware firewall? What's the software firewall". I don't really want to say cause I don't really care about how to configure those -exactly- but if I can get some random examples, I'll be really happy!

Comment: Security groups don't have IP address ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, security groups don't work like individual firewalls.  Think of it instead like a switchport that has the ability to control traffic flows, or windows firewall on a server (with some really cool tricks like only allow traffic from this other switchport or firewall)

It sounds like what you want to do is to define a rule that allows traffic only from another security group.

See the security group rules section of the docs here:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules